# LINQ - SELECT minimal value, only if collection is not null

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm

I have the following (simplified) models:

```
public class ClockinReport_PerMachine
{
    public ObservableCollection<Clockin_Categories> Categories { get; set; }
}
public class Clockin_Categories
{
    public ObservableCollection<ClockinReport_Day> Report { get; set; }
}
public class ClockinReport_Day
{
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my ViewModel I have the following:

```
public ObservableCollection<ClockinReport_PerMachine> MachineReport {get;set;}
```

Logic is as following:

- You have multiple Machines
- Each machine has several categories we report on (e.g. Error - no paper, Error - No ink, ...just an examples)
- Under each of these categories, there are daily incidents, where except for the other things, we track exact DateTime when the issue occured

I have the following script, which returns the Minimum DateTime from all **MachineReports**

```
PeriodFrom = MachineReport.Min(n => n.Categories.Min(x => x.Report.Min(z => z.Day)));
```

This LINQ loops through all Machines, the loops through all categories and looks at the Reports and checks what is the minimum DateTime (at least that's what I think it does).

The problem occurs, when **Categories** does not contain any elements. Then it returns an error saying `Sequence contains no elements`.

How can I change my LINQ, so that it would ignore Categories, if there are no elements?

**FINAL:**

In the end checking if collection is not null did not work for me, as my collection contained 0 elements (it is initialized at startup). Therefore I had to slightly edit my answer to the following:

```
PeriodFrom = MachineReport.Min(n => n.Categories.Where(b=>b.Report.Count>0).Min(x => x.Report.Max(z => z.Day)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PeriodFrom = MachineReport.Min(n => n.Categories.
                                      Where(c => c != null).
                                      Min(x => x.Report.Min(z => z.Day)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are selecting a minimum of minimums (of minimums), you could use [`DefaultIfEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360179%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method, like this:

```
PeriodFrom = MachineReport
    .SelectMany(n =>
        n.Categories.SelectMany(x =>
            x.Report.SelectMany(z =>
                (DateTime?)z.Day
            )
        )
    )
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Min();
```

Note that `Min()` will give you `null` when the sequence is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You should test if Categories is not null in your expression.
Something like

```
PeriodFrom = MachineReport.Min(n => (n.Categories != null &&
n.Categories.Min(x => x.Report.Min(z => z.Day))));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! RVid posted answer few seconds earlier, therefore had to give him the credit.